# Multiple rewrite rules links php custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new at php and I'm trying to do some rewrite rules to change the structure of some links, I tried some code I found and this code work but only for the first custom post type I indicated in the for loop, I want to do a for loop that change the links for all the custom post types names that I've indicated(the post names are in an array), here my code for my rewrite rule:

```php
function mycustomname_link($post_link, $post = 0) {
    
    if($post->post_name === $name_of_my_post) {
        
        return home_url('new' .'/'. 'posts'.'/'. $post->post_name .'/'. $post->ID . '/');
        
    }
    else{
        return $post_link;
    }
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'mycustomname_link', 1,3);

function mycustomname_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule('new/posts/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)?$', 'index.php?post_type=nature_posts&p=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action('init', 'mycustomname_rewrites_init');
```

I see that there is a return in the function so,it will apply the rewrite rules only at the first iteration and for the first custom post name, how can I do a for loop that will apply the rewrite rules for all the post_names that i will indicate and it will not stop at first iteration?

Comment: Not related to your question directly, but you should not call `flush_rewrite_rules` constantly, it is a relatively expensive call. If you are just working on a single site, my recommendation would be to remove it from the code and just make a note that if you ever add/change/delete the rewrite you, you'll also need to manually flush the permalinks which you can do by just clicking the save button in the Permalinks admin area.

Comment: To your problem, you are listing `p=` twice in the rewrite rule. Since you have the post's ID, I think you can just use `index.php?post_type=nature_posts&p=$matches[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

In the mycustomname_link function, we added a loop that iterates through the $custom_post_types array. For each custom post type, it checks if the current post type matches any of the names in the array. If there is a match, the rewrite rule will be applied.

Similarly, in the mycustomname_rewrites_init function, we added a loop to register the rewrite rules for all the custom post types in the array. Each custom post type will have its own rewrite rule.

With this modification, the rewrite rules will be applied for all the custom post types specified in the $custom_post_types array, and it will not stop at the first iteration. Make sure to update the $custom_post_types array with the names of all the custom post types you want to include in the rewrite rules.

```
function mycustomname_link($post_link, $post = 0) {
    $custom_post_types = array('name_of_my_post', 'another_post_type', 'yet_another_post_type'); // Add all your custom post type names here

    foreach ($custom_post_types as $post_type) {
        if ($post->post_type === $post_type) {
            return home_url('new' .'/'. 'posts'.'/'. $post->post_name .'/'. $post->ID . '/');
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'mycustomname_link', 10, 2);

function mycustomname_rewrites_init(){
    $custom_post_types = array('name_of_my_post', 'another_post_type', 'yet_another_post_type'); // Add all your custom post type names here

    foreach ($custom_post_types as $post_type) {
        add_rewrite_rule('new/posts/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)?$', 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type . '&p=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]', 'top');
    }

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'mycustomname_rewrites_init');
```